# Unable to update Column values with large size text?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

My table is `lists_table` and it is configure to collation `utf8_unicode_ci`. My column `file_data` is of type `LONGTEXT` and the same collation as my table.

It's input is of the form of a `json_encode($multi_dimensional_array)`. A sample of value that is input into this column is :

```
[["Header","Row","Width"],["1","2","3"]]
```

Now, when I have such a huge json_encoded variable, it shows a `NULL`. But when the value size is reduced, it enters it perfectly!

Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

**Attempts:**

I deleted my whole database and manually created all tables and columns.But nothing happens even then.

Thanks a lot!
JJ

Comment: define huge and show your table definitions.

Comment: I have shown what kind of table it.

Comment: And my column data exceeds over 65,000 characters.I'm expecting a average of 100,000 to be safe.

Comment: I get this error for LARGE values : MySQL server has gone away . But for smaller values it doesnt seem to come

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resolved. The proRefer to this : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html for all the possible reaons. In my case, I had my connection open at the starrt of my php page and closed it at end. Hence, the connection timed out.It is better if you close it in between and start another inbetween.